# How to check python scripts for f-strings which are missing the f literal? (for pre-debugging / lint)

Tags: python, debugging, pylint

I often forget to prefix formatted strings with "f".

A buggy example:  `text = "results is {result}"`
Where it should be  `text = f"results is {result}"`

I make this error A LOT; my IDE don't report it, and the program runs without exceptions.

I thought maybe to scan my source code for quoted strings, check for {,} characters, and search if it's missing a prefix "f" literal;

But it's better, i guess, to use a parser? Or maybe someone did it already?

Comment: A tool to do what you want is going to give a *lot* of false positives on code that uses `str.format` instead of f-strings.

Comment: i haven't used str.format for years; i don't think i have any sources containing that old form.

Comment: If you were to do this you'd probably want to add a check that whatever is inside the brackets is a variable and then check for the prefix, but this confounds the logic a little. Either the user didn't intend to use format string and just wants to print brackets with a word between, or they forgot to define the variable.

Comment: i understand your concerns, @MrR, however, the clever python developers used {curly braces} for a reason - it's rarely used in common strings.
Also, since i'm the "user", i know that I use them only when quoting CSS strigs or code blocks, and those aren't that common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `text = "results is {result}"` is a valid template string, so you can later use it in your program like:

```py
>>> text.format(result=1)
'results is 1'
>>> text.format(result=3)
'results is 3'
```

What you can achieve is just checking if an `f-string` does indeed use variables inside, like `pylint` and `flake8` already do.

For what you seek, however, there is something going on with PyLint:
[this issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2507) is 3 years old, but it is exactly what you need, and recently - three days ago - an user [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/4787) that is currently WIP, and should resolve your problem.

Comment: i'll chk it out. I have used str.format only once in the past 5 years, i don't mind a false negative once in a while.  OTOH, the bug i'm talking about happens twice a day...